# unexpected T_VARTIABLE on function call

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a random set of cards but I don't want duplicates, so i'm using randWithout to exude already generated numbers. However i'm getting a **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('** on the $which_card line , what am I doing wrong?

```
 $exceptions = array();

 $which_card = $this->randWithout(0,count($Card_array['Suits']-1), array $exceptions);
```

exclusion function

```
function randWithout($from, $to, array $exceptions) {
    sort($exceptions); // lets us use break; in the foreach reliably
    $number = mt_rand($from, $to - count($exceptions)); // or mt_rand()
    foreach ($exceptions as $exception) {
        if ($number >= $exception) {
            $number++; // make up for the gap
        } else /*if ($number < $exception)*/ {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->randWithout(0,count($Card_array['Suits']-1), array $exceptions);
                                                    ^---- this is causing it
```

You don't need to specify a variable holds an array on a function *call*

Comment: if i remove it i get `Unsupported operand types in` $which_card line

Comment: That `-1` inside the `count()` is suspect too  `count($Card_array['Suits'])-1`

Comment: Even if you did, type casting requires encapsulation in `()` so it would be `(array)$exceptions`

Comment: seems removing the -1 fixes the problem, how is it creating the unsupported operand type error?

Comment: @Edward because PHP doesn't know how to subtract an integer from an array, which is what `$Card_array['Suits']-1` asks it to do. Hence "unsupported operand" on the left side of the `-`.

Comment: @michaelBerkowski that does make sense I thought it would perform the count operation first but i see my error now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$which_card = $this->randWithout(0,count($Card_array['Suits'])-1, $exceptions)
```

How about removing the "array" from the function and moving the -1 to tye outside of count? I agree it seems a bit fishy